# Phython Flask SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, sqlite

I have flask code in **helloflask.py** and **abcd.py** in the same folder:

```
import abcd as abc
    @app.route("/ddata")
    def stuff1():

        p=abc.run('somefile.txt')
        return json.dumps(p)
```

**abcd.py** has following code

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\me\Desktop\Python\my.db')
cursor=connection.cursor()

def dbcall(ip_rel,c_mac):
    sql="select count(*) from myDB"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    row=cursor.fetchone()
    count =row[0]

    return count #I am returning a list here in my original code
```

When I run `helloflask.py` I get following error while retrieving rows:

ERROR:

> File "C:\Users\mvahuje\Desktop\Python\Application\Dsharkclass.py",
>   line 25, in dbcall    cursor.execute(sql) ProgrammingError: SQLite
>   objects created in a thread can only be used in that sa me thread.The
>   object was created in thread id 15108 and this is thread id 14488

This has something to do with thread permissions `sqlite3`. But I am not sure what could I do additionally to get it working.

Individually out `abcd.py` works perfectly fine when called into other code.

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393554/python-sqlite3-and-concurrency

Comment: Thanks @gplayer For me following worked connection = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\me\Desktop\Python\my.db',check_same_thread=False)