# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. In django 2.2

Tags: python-3.x, django, sqlite

I'm facing this issue in test server. but not in production. I tried some of the solutions like python manage.py runserver --noreload and edit
/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py this file.

Mentioned in the document.

https://github.com/django/django/commit/5bf2c87ece216b00a55a6ec0d6c824c9edabf188

This the error message look like,

sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 140000522213120 and this is thread id 140000744696768.

Please suggest me a solution to rectify this problem, Anyone faced this issue before. Help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that SQLite has to deal with conflicts arising due to concurrent access by multiple threads i.e., SQLite database created and accessed by one thread cannot allow another thread to access it. This may result from following scenarios:

1. global connection objects are created which are then accessed later by different threads
2. connection objects are not closed properly between different connections

Its always recommended that an ORM is used to deal with databases and efficiently manage their connection lifecycles. For Sqlite, the most widely used ORM is [SqlAlchemy](https://auth0.com/blog/sqlalchemy-orm-tutorial-for-python-developers/). Using an ORM can probably fix the issue.

However, for very simple applications, where using an ORM is just an overkill, you can tweak the way connection is created to the Sqlite database by allowing concurrent access. This can be done by setting `check_same_thread` parameter to `False` while establishing the connection:

```
def initDB(self, file_path):
    self.file_path = file_path
    self.cx = sqlite3.connect(file_path, check_same_thread=False)
    self.cx.execute(self.create_table_str)
    self.cx.execute(self.create_detail_table_str)
    print("init the table strucutre successfully")
```

Having said that, setting up Sqlite connection this way lays responsibility to [handle concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393554/python-sqlite3-and-concurrency) on the application instead of the database and user should ensure that write operations to the database are serialized in order to avoid any dirty writes/updates.

> Note: When using sqlalchemy, its important to use the right libraries and code segregation. I have particularly found this [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/use-flask-and-sqlalchemy-not-flask-sqlalchemy-5a64fafe22a4) helpful as well.