# How to automatically delete row after 10 minutes after creation

Tags: python, sqlite

Suppose I create a database and add desired tables, columns with this code:

```py
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("clients.db", check_same_thread=False)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers(user_id INT, user_name, dt_string)") 
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO customers VALUES(?, ?. ?);""", (user_id, user_name, dt_string))
connection.commit()
```

Now I know I can delete this row upon entry with this code

```py
cursor.execute("""DELETE FROM customers WHERE user_id=?;""", (user_id,) )
connection.commit()
```

How can I wait for a certain amount of time before removing this entry? I know it's achievable using `time.sleep` and `threading` but I wanted to know if there is any other way.

Comment: I don't think SQLite has this natively. Depending on your actual goals, you could just store the creation time in the record and include a condition on the select query to only extract records newer than `now - TTL`.

Comment: thanks a ton @jonrsharpe i never thought of this approach , it should work

Comment: Have you looked at the `sched` module?

Comment: @couteau actually i don't want to use any background services cause they gets a bit complex to handle and even crashes my website sometimes (idrk why) . Anyways I implemented jonrsharpe idea and it works completely fine. Thanks for giving time

Comment: Using comment from @jonrsharpe, you could use a view to access the data which will make the test with the creation time under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understand that `sqlite` is serverless. That is its whole purpose. So there is nothing doing anything fancy in the background.

It is not like SQL servers, that may have some procedures and stuff that could implement this kind of temporality (I am not aware of anything like that in MySql neither. But, I am not well versed into it, so that doesn't prove that it doesn't exist. And at least it could exist. Redis, for example have such things).

So here, if someone make the row disappear after a while, it is you. Since there is nobody else. Sqlite is just a library to open and read files, not an API to talk  with "someone else", that is to a server.

So, one method, for example, could be to use a timer

```py
from threading import Timer

def delUser(userid):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""DELETE FROM customers WHERE user_id=?;""", (user_id,) )
    connection.commit()

#...
Timer(10, delUser, (user_id,)).start()
```

But of course, you'll have to deal with multithreading caveout, if the main thread may still be writing during that time.

You've already added the `check_same_thread=False` flag (I don't know why btw. I needed it, but you didn't so far. Probably because you've already tried similar solutions).

But you also have to handle some semaphores or anyway to ensure that there is only one thread writing at a time. Quote from documentation

> When using multiple threads with the same connection writing
> operations should be serialized by the user to avoid data corruption

There is a discussion about this [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393554/python-sqlite3-and-concurrency)

Answer (score -2):

I do not work with sqlLite but I suggest creating a task for deletion. In the task, you could wait ten minutes and then delete the record. this task could be sent to the background so it did not block your program. you could use reddis to manage background tasks.

Answer (score -3):

If you don't want to use `time.sleep` to delete the entry on the table, you can simply use this method to delete the entry from the database.

1. First of all, add a created_at column to your table. We will store the timestamp of the creation of the row. (When you are inserting the data, don't forget to add the current timestamp in the table).

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers(user_id INT, user_name TEXT, dt_string TEXT, created_at TIME)")
```

```
import time

# Get the current timestamp
enter code here
created_at = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

# Insert the entry with the created_at timestamp
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO customers VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);", (user_id, user_name, dt_string, created_at))
connection.commit()
```

2. Now you can periodically check and delete the rows that have reached their deletion period. So just add the `deletion time period` to the `created_at` time and if it's behind the current time, it's time to delete that item. For this you can simply make a cron job or background task scheduler(Read about cron jobs).

Hope it helps!